# clone html form WITH values

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, clone

I am trying to duplicate a form after it has been filled out. So the user fills out the form then hits submit. then a new window opens with the full html form, images, and styling included AND the values so they can print the filled out version. i tried .html() and .clone(). but neither seem to work.

any help is much apperciated. and please don't hesitate to ask questions.

Comment: `clone()` seems to work fine: http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/te3LX/ Maybe you should post your code too.

Comment: Correction: It seems only to work for `input` elements.

Comment: ahh ok. http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1591-Ask-Ben-Print-Part-Of-A-Web-Page-With-jQuery.htm i started with this. maybe it will help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Post your code for creating the popup.

You may need to use [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to copy the values over.
http://jsfiddle.net/Na6GN/2/

```
$('#myForm :input').each(function() {
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#newForm').val($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: So i have to serialize all the values and then iterate through them to repopulate the form? I was afraid of that. I just hoped there was an easier solution. Thank you for replying

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine:

**JS:**

```
$('btnclone').click(function() {
    var mywindow = window.open();
    $(mywindow.document.body).append($('form').eq(0).clone());
});
```

**Html Code**

```
<form>
    <input name='test' />
</form>

<input type="button" value="Clone" name="btnclone" id="btnclone" />
```

Comment: but i have the form in a div. i have lots of img tags. so eq(0) isn't working for me. also when i try your theory with my script i get [object object] displayed. I can't figure out with is causing my choosen block of code to turn into an oject!!!???